# Creating a drupal taxonomy from a SPARQL endpoint

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, sparql

I've been stuck with this for a while.

I want to create a live link between my Drupal7 site and a SKOS/RDF web thesaurus.
The web thesaurus has a SPARQL endpoint.
I already wrote a SPARQL statement that returns me everything I want to be in my taxonomy.

I just don't know what to do on the drupal site of this.
There are possibilities to build views based on SPARQL queries, but I have no idea how I might convert that to a proper taxonomy.

Modules that could probably help solving this riddle are:

https://www.drupal.org/project/sparql_views

https://www.drupal.org/project/web_taxonomy

I'm still a beginner when it comes to Drupal, so what I'd need is a rather detailed explanation.
But any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: This question should probably be asked on the Drupal site.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Web Taxonomy module is what you are looking for. It can connect to your endpoint, help with autocomplete and create the taxonomy entry locally. You would need to create your own plugin for the module, but that doesn't look too difficult if you have a little bit of php knowledge. I looked at the DBPedia (https://www.drupal.org/project/wt_dbpedia) plugin and it is less than 150 loc. You could use that module as the starting point for your own work. If you don't know php, you might want to engage a developer to help out.